# Rails - Making a page viewable to admin only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a super simple question. I have a page that lists all the products in my app. I just want to make that page view-able by admin only. But products/new I want everyone to be able to see clearly.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "admin",           :default => false
  end
```

**products controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login
    before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :destory]
    before_filter :correct_user, only: :destory

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new 
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])
    if @product.valid? 
      @product.save
        render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
        render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end
```

Comment: if you use devise to take care of your authentication then you can then use the built in helper :authenticate_user, in respect to admin just look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278534/devise-authenticate-user

Comment: I don't use devise as it says only experienced rails devs should use it and this is my first non tutorial app.

Comment: dont listen to that , IMHO the documentation for devise explains everything for all levels, jump in, whats the worst that can happen?

Comment: @Richlewis, the worst that can happen is that he learns Sweet FA.

Comment: or he may actually learn something new..woah lets not get too crazy :)

Comment: can you post `require_login`, `current_user` and `corrent_user` method ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put in your controller

```
before_filter :authorize_admin, only: :index
```

and in application_controller.rb

```
def authorize_admin
    redirect_to :back, status: 401 unless current_user.admin
    #redirects to previous page
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller write

before_filter :admin_user

and create a def  like this

```
private
def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? It's not exactly a thought-provoking question, you have an boolean for admin, and you want to restrict an action to admin only, so just check `current_user.admin`.

```
before_filter :require_admin, only: :index

private
  def require_admin
    if !current_user.admin
      if request.xhr?
        head :unauthorized # for asynchronous/api requests, if you want.
      else
        render 'access/no_access' and return # or whatever.
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

in your ProductsController you can add a function that verify if the user is an admin or not and use filter for the view you want to protect like this :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :index # here you specify the action (for views) to protect
  .
  .
  .
  private
  .
  .
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
 end
```

i hope that help you

Comment: His User table already have admin attribute. Look at the schema carefully

Answer (score 1):

add `correct_user` method and `admin_user` method under private on your controller or create another method with following defination and add `:only => :index` on `before_filter` for admin.

```
before_filter :require_login
before_filter :correct_user
before_filter :admin_user, :only => :index


private

def correct_user
  redirect_to(root_path) if current_user.nil?  && !current_user.admin?
end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Check Railscasts Episode [Super Simple Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication).

Actually, Ryan Bates is a big fan of making authentication from scratch, he made [many episode](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=25) on this topics. Have a look on them and you will surely get some good ideas.

Comment: Judging by his schema, he already has some authentication in place.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I don't think so. If you don't want to watch the whole video. Read the ASCIIcast instead, no the show notes.

Comment: I'm talking about the OP. Read his question again.